# Sim card manager - Mobile Data sim card assignment not persistent

Tags: settings, mobile-data, dual-sim

I am using Samsung A50, which is dual sim. In the **Sim card manager** I set my SIM 1 to be the one for **Mobile Data**, but every time I reboot the device, the setting gets reset back to SIM 2, and so I need to make sure to revisit and adjust it. (I have just received an OS update so I had it all reproduced quite clearly.)

Not sure:

1. why it is resetting, in the first place. Isn't that setting supposed to be persistent across reboots?
2. what causes SIM 2 to prevail? Is it that because it is the first sim card that manages to establish data connection? Programmatically speaking, I would assume that SIM 1 would prevail as the one with 0 index.

Is there any other setting that could mess with all that? Can I somehow mitigate this problem?